# Accessing database for Live tile update

Tags: database, uwp, live-tile

so Im doing a live tile update in UWP project and I need to access my database to retrieve the data and update the tile. But the project that I made that has the database has a reference to the RuntimeComponent, so I cant make a circular reference and make the project known to the RuntimeComponent. therefore I cant use my database. I have seen [This MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/update-a-live-tile-from-a-background-task) which shows the method "GetMSDNBlogFeed" in their example, but it gets the data from the web, not from a local database. what do I do?

Comment: What kind of your database is ?SQLite? What  "the database has a reference to the RuntimeComponent" mean? Why it has a circular reference?  Could you please detail your question?

Comment: yes it is SQLite
and I said :  the project that I made that has the database has a reference
its 2 projects in the solution, the main one and the RuntimeComponent.

Comment: Did you mean in one solution you have two projects, the main one and the component,  and you have one database, both two projects need to access the database? So where is the database located?How you access it now?  Did you mean the  main project referenced the component? As I said I'm not sure what "database referenced component mean", how a database referenced a RuntimeComponent?